# How can I inject a popover inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I am using an `iframe` to display a page in the same domain and I would like to inject a bootstrap popover inside the `iframe`: is there a way of doing it?

I am currently trying:

Javascript:

```
var iframe = $('#editor-iframe');
iframe.load(function (){
        var contents = iframe.contents();
        var element = contents.find('a');
        element.popover();
});
```

HTML (partial content from the iframe):

```
<a href="#" tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" 
        data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="Dismissible popover" 
        data-content="And here's some amazing content. 
        It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
```

I try to click on the `a` element, but nothing happens and no error messages are given. It works fine outside of the iframe, but I don't know why it does not work on the `iframe`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems too few info. Can you setup jsfiddle with your issue? Otherwise just make sure that you have that script referenced in your iframe and that **element** found e.g. console.log(element); Also check popover works with array of elements.

Comment: The element is found, it shows exactly the content from the HTML I posted. I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chgv41Lr/ but somehow the popovers are being activated inside the iframe, which is the behavior I wanted to do